# How to make a thread in MFC for moving slider control with respect to audio file that is being played?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, audio-player

I was able to move SliderControl according to the position using CSliderCtrl::GetPos , being played by the program. (This is a part of my Music Player MFC project).

But I need to do this automatically without any notification/events ....

I thought of creating a thread that will move slider after clicking on play button.

Answer (score 3):

You generally want to have exactly one thread updating the UI (and doing as little else as possible).

It would almost certainly work better to have a secondary thread playing the music. It can send a message to the UI thread, and the UI thread updates the slider control position when it receives that message.

Answer (score 1):

It is always good to update the UI from the main thread instead of adding a new thread for updating UI. Better you can perform your background tasks by using a worker thread and update the UI by sending a message to the main thread when ever required.

In your case, you can have a worker thread to play the music and send a message to the main thread to update the slider position.

```
::SendMessage( AfxGetMainWnd()->m_hWnd, Message_Id, ( WPARAM )&String, 0 );
```

You can use the APIs CSliderCtrl::SetPos() to update the position.

Comment: And how about PostMessage()?